# Using plotly in Jupyter to create animated chart in off-line mode

Tags: python, plotly

I've been trying to get the "Filled-Area Animation in Python" example to work using plotly in offline mode in a Jupyter notebook. The example can be found here: https://plot.ly/python/filled-area-animation/

Since I'm in off-line mode, I create a local csv file containing dummy data to use as the data source, then read the csv using pandas dataframes:

```
# Add the following line
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
.....
# Read csv instead of using get_data_yahoo
#appl = web.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', '2016-01-01', '2016-11-30')
appl = pd.read_csv("C:\\test.csv")
apple_data_matrix = appl.head(10)
.....
# Use offline version of iplot
#py.iplot(table, filename='apple_data_table')
iplot(table, filename='apple_data_table')
```

So far so good.
The code to "Make the Grid" remains the same - except commenting out the last line which is on-line only:

```
def to_unix_time(dt):
    epoch =  datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)
    return (dt - epoch).total_seconds() * 1000

appl_price = list(appl['Adj Close'])
my_columns = []
for k in range(len(appl.index) - 1):
    my_columns.append(Column(appl.index[:k + 1], 'x{}'.format(k + 1)))   
    my_columns.append(Column(appl_price[:k + 1], 'y{}'.format(k + 1)))
grid = Grid(my_columns)
#py.grid_ops.upload(grid, 'AAPL-daily-stock-price' + str(time.time()), auto_open=False)
```

The final section of the code ('Make the figure') is where I'm struggling. This is the code which draws the chart and animates it:

```
data=[dict(type='scatter',
           xsrc=grid.get_column_reference('x1'),
           ysrc= grid.get_column_reference('y1'),
           name='AAPL',
           mode='lines',
           line=dict(color= 'rgb(114, 186, 59)'),
           fill='tozeroy',
           fillcolor='rgba(114, 186, 59, 0.5)')]

axis=dict(ticklen=4,
          mirror=True,
          zeroline=False,
          showline=True,
          autorange=False,
          showgrid=False)

layout = dict(title='AAPL Daily Stock Price',
              font=dict(family='Balto'),
              showlegend=False,
              autosize=False,
              width=800,
              height=400,
              xaxis=dict(axis, **{'nticks':12, 'tickangle':-45,
                                  'range': [to_unix_time(datetime(2016, 1, 4)),
                                            to_unix_time(datetime(2016, 11, 30))]}),
              yaxis=dict(axis, **{'title': '$', 'range':[0,120]}),
              updatemenus=[dict(type='buttons',
                                showactive=False,
                                y=1,
                                x=1.1,
                                xanchor='right',
                                yanchor='top',
                                pad=dict(t=0, r=10),
                                buttons=[dict(label='Play',
                                              method='animate',
                                              args=[None, dict(frame=dict(duration=50, redraw=False), 
                                                               transition=dict(duration=0),
                                                               fromcurrent=True,
                                                               mode='immediate')])])])

frames=[{'data':[{'xsrc': grid.get_column_reference('x{}'.format(k + 1)),
                  'ysrc': grid.get_column_reference('y{}'.format(k + 1))}],
         'traces': [0]
        } for k in range(len(appl.index) - 1)]

fig=dict(data=data, layout=layout, frames=frames)
py.icreate_animations(fig, 'AAPL-stockprice' + str(time.time()))
```

py.icreate_animations (last line) is not available in off-line mode. I've tried replacing it with plotly.offline.iplot(fig) but get the following stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-c3918e48e33a> in <module>()
     46 fig=dict(data=data, layout=layout, frames=frames)
     47 #fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout, frames=frames)
---> 48 plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
     49 #iplot.create_animations(fig, 'AAPL-stockprice' + str(time.time()))
     50 #py.icreate_animations(fig, 'AAPL-stockprice' + str(time.time()))

C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\offline\offline.py in iplot(figure_or_data, show_link, link_text, validate, image, filename, image_width, image_height)
    340     )
    341 
--> 342     figure = tools.return_figure_from_figure_or_data(figure_or_data, validate)
    343 
    344     # Though it can add quite a bit to the display-bundle size, we include

C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\tools.py in return_figure_from_figure_or_data(figure_or_data, validate_figure)
   1378 
   1379         try:
-> 1380             graph_objs.Figure(figure)
   1381         except exceptions.PlotlyError as err:
   1382             raise exceptions.PlotlyError("Invalid 'figure_or_data' argument. "

C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\graph_objs.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1110 
   1111     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
-> 1112         super(Figure, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   1113         if 'data' not in self:
   1114             self.data = Data(_parent=self, _parent_key='data')

C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\graph_objs.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    375         d = {key: val for key, val in dict(*args, **kwargs).items()}
    376         for key, val in d.items():
--> 377             self.__setitem__(key, val, _raise=_raise)
    378 
    379     def __dir__(self):

C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\graph_objs.py in __setitem__(self, key, value, _raise)
    430 
    431         if self._get_attribute_role(key) == 'object':
--> 432             value = self._value_to_graph_object(key, value, _raise=_raise)
    433             if not isinstance(value, (PlotlyDict, PlotlyList)):
    434                 return

C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\graph_objs.py in _value_to_graph_object(self, key, value, _raise)
    541         # this can be `None` when `_raise == False`
    542         return GraphObjectFactory.create(key, value, _raise=_raise,
--> 543                                          _parent=self, _parent_key=key)
    544 
    545     def help(self, attribute=None, return_help=False):

C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\graph_objs.py in create(object_name, *args, **kwargs)
    791         class_name = graph_reference.OBJECT_NAME_TO_CLASS_NAME.get(object_name)
    792         if class_name in ['Figure', 'Data', 'Frames']:
--> 793             return globals()[class_name](*args, **kwargs)
    794         else:
    795             kwargs['_name'] = object_name

C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\graph_objs.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    156 
    157         for index, value in enumerate(list(*args)):
--> 158             value = self._value_to_graph_object(index, value, _raise=_raise)
    159 
    160             if isinstance(value, PlotlyBase):

C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\graph_objs.py in _value_to_graph_object(self, index, value, _raise)
   1010         return GraphObjectFactory.create(item, _raise=_raise,
   1011                                          _parent=self,
-> 1012                                          _parent_key=index, **value)
   1013 
   1014     def get_data(self, flatten=False):

C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\graph_objs.py in create(object_name, *args, **kwargs)
    797                 return PlotlyList(*args, **kwargs)
    798             else:
--> 799                 return PlotlyDict(*args, **kwargs)
    800 
    801 

C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\graph_objs.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    375         d = {key: val for key, val in dict(*args, **kwargs).items()}
    376         for key, val in d.items():
--> 377             self.__setitem__(key, val, _raise=_raise)
    378 
    379     def __dir__(self):

C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\graph_objs.py in __setitem__(self, key, value, _raise)
    400         if key.endswith('src'):
    401             if key in self._get_valid_attributes():
--> 402                 value = graph_objs_tools.assign_id_to_src(key, value)
    403                 return super(PlotlyDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
    404 

C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\graph_objs\graph_objs_tools.py in assign_id_to_src(src_name, src_value)
    254     if src_id == '':
    255         err = exceptions.COLUMN_NOT_YET_UPLOADED_MESSAGE
--> 256         err.format(column_name=src_value.name, reference=src_name)
    257         raise exceptions.InputError(err)
    258     return src_id

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Can anyone help workout how to get the animation to work in offline mode.

Thanks in advance -- Simon

Answer (score 0):

This issue is addressed in 
[Plotly icreate_animations offline on Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45780920/plotly-icreate-animations-offline-on-jupyter-notebook)

According to that answer, the plotly.grid_objs Grid function is not supported offline.  He transitions the code to use DataFrames instead, which avoids the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but if anybody is trying to figure it out, the only difference is the usage of `from plotly.grid_objs import Grid, Column` as data holders which can be easily replaced by a `pandas.DataFrame` or a `dict`.

By using a `dict`, replace the following code block:

```
my_columns = []
for k in range(len(appl.index) - 1):
    my_columns.append(Column(appl.index[:k + 1], 'x{}'.format(k + 1)))   
    my_columns.append(Column(appl_price[:k + 1], 'y{}'.format(k + 1)))
grid = Grid(my_columns)
```

with:

```
my_columns = {}
for k in range(len(appl.Date) - 1):
    my_columns['x{}'.format(k + 1)] = list(appl.Date)[:k + 1]
    my_columns['y{}'.format(k + 1)] = appl_price[:k + 1]
```

So whats happening? Plotly's `Grid` use the method `get_column_reference` later on which works exactly like a `dict`, it stores key value pairs that are used for the plot start as well as for its `frames`.

From there, replace all reference to the `Grid` to your created `dict` which is stored as `my_columns` from our change made above. Finally use `iplot` from the offline Python API instead of `icreate_animations`.

The second block of code:

```
data=[dict(type='scatter',
           x= my_columns['x1'],
           y= my_columns['y1'],
           name='AAPL',
           mode='lines',
           line=dict(color= 'rgb(114, 186, 59)'),
           fill='tozeroy',
           fillcolor='rgba(114, 186, 59, 0.5)')]

axis=dict(ticklen=4,
          mirror=True,
          zeroline=False,
          showline=True,
          autorange=False,
          showgrid=False)

layout = dict(title='AAPL Daily Stock Price',
              font=dict(family='Balto'),
              showlegend=False,
              autosize=False,
              xaxis=dict(axis, **{'nticks':12, 'tickangle':-45,
                                  'range': [to_unix_time(datetime(2015, 2, 17)),
                                            to_unix_time(datetime(2016, 11, 30))]}),
              yaxis=dict(axis, **{'title': '$', 'range':[0,170]}),
              updatemenus=[dict(type='buttons',
                                showactive=False,
                                y=1,
                                x=1.1,
                                xanchor='right',
                                yanchor='top',
                                pad=dict(t=0, r=10),
                                buttons=[dict(label='Play',
                                              method='animate',
                                              args=[None, dict(frame=dict(duration=50, redraw=True), 
                                                               transition=dict(duration=0),
                                                               fromcurrent=True,
                                                               mode='immediate')])])])

frames=[{'data':[{'x': my_columns['x{}'.format(k + 1)],
                  'y': my_columns['y{}'.format(k + 1)]}],
         'traces': [0]
        } for k in range(len(appl.Date) - 1)]


fig=dict(data=data, layout=layout, frames=frames)
iplot(fig,
      show_link=False, config=dict(displaylogo=False, modeBarButtonsToRemove=['sendDataToCloud']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Gone are the days when you had to worry about using Plotly in an [offline mode](https://medium.com/plotly/plotly-py-4-0-is-here-offline-only-express-first-displayable-anywhere-fc444e5659ee). In order to achieve the same chart that your source produces:

[image]

...you can now build on this [excellent example from the Plotly community forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/cumulative-lines-animation-in-python/25707), add the following:

```
fig.data[1].fill = 'tozeroy'
```

... and get this:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go  #plotly 4.0.0rc1


df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/finance-charts-apple.csv')
low = df['AAPL.Low'].tolist()
high = np.array(df['AAPL.High'])+20 # artificially added 20 to get the second graph above the first one

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=df.Date[:2],
                    y=low[:2],
                    mode='lines',
                    line=dict(width=1.5))

trace2 = go.Scatter(x = df.Date[:2],
                    y = high[:2],
                    mode='lines',
                    line=dict(width=1.5))

frames = [dict(data= [dict(type='scatter',
                           x=df.Date[:k+1],
                           y=low[:k+1]),
                      dict(type='scatter',
                           x=df.Date[:k+1],
                           y=high[:k+1])],
               traces= [0, 1],  #this means that  frames[k]['data'][0]  updates trace1, and   frames[k]['data'][1], trace2 
              )for k  in  range(1, len(low)-1)] 

layout = go.Layout(width=650,
                   height=400,
                   showlegend=False,
                   hovermode='closest',
                   updatemenus=[dict(type='buttons', showactive=False,
                                y=1.05,
                                x=1.15,
                                xanchor='right',
                                yanchor='top',
                                pad=dict(t=0, r=10),
                                buttons=[dict(label='Play',
                                              method='animate',
                                              args=[None, 
                                                    dict(frame=dict(duration=3, 
                                                                    redraw=False),
                                                         transition=dict(duration=0),
                                                         fromcurrent=True,
                                                         mode='immediate')])])])


layout.update(xaxis =dict(range=[df.Date[0], df.Date[len(df)-1]], autorange=False),
              yaxis =dict(range=[min(low)-0.5, high.max()+0.5], autorange=False));
fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1, trace2], frames=frames, layout=layout)
f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)


fig.data[1].fill = 'tozeroy'

fig.show()
```