# Plotly icreate_animations offline on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I am trying to replicate [this plotly tutorial](https://plot.ly/python/gapminder-example/) on a Jupyter Notebook with a dataset that matches the one given in the example, I just had to change the name of one column. The issue here is that being offline the command

```
py.icreate_animations(figure)
```

which in offline notebook mode becomes

```
icreate_animations(figure)
```

is not recognized. Furthermore, if I simply try the 
    iplot(figure)
command, which I use for static plots, a very long error is raised:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-b81a66612f63> in <module>()
     38 figure['layout']['sliders'] = [sliders_dict]
     39 
---> 40 iplot(figure)

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/offline/offline.pyc in iplot(figure_or_data, show_link, link_text, validate, image, filename, image_width, image_height, config)
    330     config.setdefault('linkText', link_text)
    331 
--> 332     figure = tools.return_figure_from_figure_or_data(figure_or_data, validate)
    333 
    334     # Though it can add quite a bit to the display-bundle size, we include

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/tools.pyc in return_figure_from_figure_or_data(figure_or_data, validate_figure)
   1383 
   1384         try:
-> 1385             graph_objs.Figure(figure)
   1386         except exceptions.PlotlyError as err:
   1387             raise exceptions.PlotlyError("Invalid 'figure_or_data' argument. "

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1159 
   1160     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
-> 1161         super(Figure, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   1162         if 'data' not in self:
   1163             self.data = Data(_parent=self, _parent_key='data')

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    375         d = {key: val for key, val in dict(*args, **kwargs).items()}
    376         for key, val in d.items():
--> 377             self.__setitem__(key, val, _raise=_raise)
    378 
    379     def __dir__(self):

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in __setitem__(self, key, value, _raise)
    430 
    431         if self._get_attribute_role(key) == 'object':
--> 432             value = self._value_to_graph_object(key, value, _raise=_raise)
    433             if not isinstance(value, (PlotlyDict, PlotlyList)):
    434                 return

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in _value_to_graph_object(self, key, value, _raise)
    541         # this can be `None` when `_raise == False`
    542         return GraphObjectFactory.create(key, value, _raise=_raise,
--> 543                                          _parent=self, _parent_key=key)
    544 
    545     def help(self, attribute=None, return_help=False):

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in create(object_name, *args, **kwargs)
    791         class_name = graph_reference.OBJECT_NAME_TO_CLASS_NAME.get(object_name)
    792         if class_name in ['Figure', 'Data', 'Frames']:
--> 793             return globals()[class_name](*args, **kwargs)
    794         else:
    795             kwargs['_name'] = object_name

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    156 
    157         for index, value in enumerate(list(*args)):
--> 158             value = self._value_to_graph_object(index, value, _raise=_raise)
    159 
    160             if isinstance(value, PlotlyBase):

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in _value_to_graph_object(self, index, value, _raise)
   1291             return value
   1292         return super(Frames, self)._value_to_graph_object(index, value,
-> 1293                                                           _raise=_raise)
   1294 
   1295     def to_string(self, level=0, indent=4, eol='\n',

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in _value_to_graph_object(self, index, value, _raise)
    221                 return GraphObjectFactory.create(item, _raise=_raise,
    222                                                  _parent=self,
--> 223                                                  _parent_key=index, **value)
    224             except exceptions.PlotlyGraphObjectError:
    225                 if i == len(items) and _raise:

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in create(object_name, *args, **kwargs)
    797                 return PlotlyList(*args, **kwargs)
    798             else:
--> 799                 return PlotlyDict(*args, **kwargs)
    800 
    801 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    375         d = {key: val for key, val in dict(*args, **kwargs).items()}
    376         for key, val in d.items():
--> 377             self.__setitem__(key, val, _raise=_raise)
    378 
    379     def __dir__(self):

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in __setitem__(self, key, value, _raise)
    430 
    431         if self._get_attribute_role(key) == 'object':
--> 432             value = self._value_to_graph_object(key, value, _raise=_raise)
    433             if not isinstance(value, (PlotlyDict, PlotlyList)):
    434                 return

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in _value_to_graph_object(self, key, value, _raise)
    541         # this can be `None` when `_raise == False`
    542         return GraphObjectFactory.create(key, value, _raise=_raise,
--> 543                                          _parent=self, _parent_key=key)
    544 
    545     def help(self, attribute=None, return_help=False):

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in create(object_name, *args, **kwargs)
    791         class_name = graph_reference.OBJECT_NAME_TO_CLASS_NAME.get(object_name)
    792         if class_name in ['Figure', 'Data', 'Frames']:
--> 793             return globals()[class_name](*args, **kwargs)
    794         else:
    795             kwargs['_name'] = object_name

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    156 
    157         for index, value in enumerate(list(*args)):
--> 158             value = self._value_to_graph_object(index, value, _raise=_raise)
    159 
    160             if isinstance(value, PlotlyBase):

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in _value_to_graph_object(self, index, value, _raise)
   1059         return GraphObjectFactory.create(item, _raise=_raise,
   1060                                          _parent=self,
-> 1061                                          _parent_key=index, **value)
   1062 
   1063     def get_data(self, flatten=False):

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in create(object_name, *args, **kwargs)
    797                 return PlotlyList(*args, **kwargs)
    798             else:
--> 799                 return PlotlyDict(*args, **kwargs)
    800 
    801 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    375         d = {key: val for key, val in dict(*args, **kwargs).items()}
    376         for key, val in d.items():
--> 377             self.__setitem__(key, val, _raise=_raise)
    378 
    379     def __dir__(self):

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs.pyc in __setitem__(self, key, value, _raise)
    400         if key.endswith('src'):
    401             if key in self._get_valid_attributes():
--> 402                 value = graph_objs_tools.assign_id_to_src(key, value)
    403                 return super(PlotlyDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
    404 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/graph_objs_tools.pyc in assign_id_to_src(src_name, src_value)
    254     if src_id == '':
    255         err = exceptions.COLUMN_NOT_YET_UPLOADED_MESSAGE
--> 256         err.format(column_name=src_value.name, reference=src_name)
    257         raise exceptions.InputError(err)
    258     return src_id

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

So, does anyone know how to make that plot in offline mode?

EDIT: I upload the whole code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from __future__ import division
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
init_notebook_mode()

from plotly.grid_objs import Grid, Column
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF 

dataset=pd.read_csv('gdp_mod_copia.csv')

years_from_col = set(dataset['year'])
years_ints = sorted(list(years_from_col))
years = [str(year) for year in years_ints]


# make list of continents
continents = []
for continent in dataset['continent']:
    if continent not in continents: 
        continents.append(continent)

columns = []
# make grid
for year in years:
    for continent in continents:
        dataset_by_year = dataset[dataset['year'] == int(year)]
        dataset_by_year_and_cont = dataset_by_year[dataset_by_year['continent'] == continent]
        for col_name in dataset_by_year_and_cont:
            # each column name is unique
            column_name = '{year}+{continent}+{header}_grid'.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header=col_name
            )
            a_column = Column(list(dataset_by_year_and_cont[col_name]), column_name)
            columns.append(a_column)

grid = Grid(columns)



figure = {
    'data': [],
    'layout': {},
    'frames': [],
    'config': {'scrollzoom': True}
}

# fill in most of layout
figure['layout']['xaxis'] = {'range': [30, 85], 'title': 'Life Expectancy', 'gridcolor': '#FFFFFF'}
figure['layout']['yaxis'] = {'title': 'GDP per Capita', 'type': 'log', 'gridcolor': '#FFFFFF'}
figure['layout']['hovermode'] = 'closest'
figure['layout']['plot_bgcolor'] = 'rgb(223, 232, 243)'
figure['layout']['slider'] = {
    'args': [
        'slider.value', {
            'duration': 400,
            'ease': 'cubic-in-out'
        }
    ],
    'initialValue': '2007',
    'plotlycommand': 'animate',
    'values': years,
    'visible': True
}

figure['layout']['updatemenus'] = [
    {
        'buttons': [
            {
                'args': [None, {'frame': {'duration': 500, 'redraw': False},
                         'fromcurrent': True, 'transition': {'duration': 300, 'easing': 'quadratic-in-out'}}],
                'label': 'Play',
                'method': 'animate'
            },
            {
                'args': [[None], {'frame': {'duration': 0, 'redraw': False}, 'mode': 'immediate',
                'transition': {'duration': 0}}],
                'label': 'Pause',
                'method': 'animate'
            }
        ],
        'direction': 'left',
        'pad': {'r': 10, 't': 87},
        'showactive': False,
        'type': 'buttons',
        'x': 0.1,
        'xanchor': 'right',
        'y': 0,
        'yanchor': 'top'
    }
]
sliders_dict = {
    'active': 0,
    'yanchor': 'top',
    'xanchor': 'left',
    'currentvalue': {
        'font': {'size': 20},
        'prefix': 'Year:',
        'visible': True,
        'xanchor': 'right'
    },
    'transition': {'duration': 300, 'easing': 'cubic-in-out'},
    'pad': {'b': 10, 't': 50},
    'len': 0.9,
    'x': 0.1,
    'y': 0,
    'steps': []
}


custom_colors = {
    'Asia': 'rgb(171, 99, 250)',
    'Europe': 'rgb(230, 99, 250)',
    'Africa': 'rgb(99, 110, 250)',
    'Americas': 'rgb(25, 211, 243)',
    #'Oceania': 'rgb(9, 255, 255)' 
    'Oceania': 'rgb(50, 170, 255)'
}

col_name_template = '{year}+{continent}+{header}_grid'
year = 2007
for continent in continents:
    data_dict = {
        'xsrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
            year=year, continent=continent, header='GDP_per_capita'
        )),
        'ysrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
            year=year, continent=continent, header='Life_satisfaction'
        )),
        'mode': 'markers',
        'textsrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
            year=year, continent=continent, header='country'
        )),
        'marker': {
            'sizemode': 'area',
            'sizeref': 200000,
            'sizesrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
                 year=year, continent=continent, header='Total_population'
            )),
            'color': custom_colors[continent]
        },
        'name': continent
    }
    figure['data'].append(data_dict)


for year in years:
    frame = {'data': [], 'name': str(year)}
    for continent in continents:
        data_dict = {
            'xsrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
            year=year, continent=continent, header='GDP_per_capita'
            )),
            'ysrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
            year=year, continent=continent, header='Life_satisfaction'
            )),
            'mode': 'markers',
            'textsrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header='country'
                )),
            'marker': {
                'sizemode': 'area',
                'sizeref': 200000,
                'sizesrc': grid.get_column_reference(col_name_template.format(
                    year=year, continent=continent, header='Total_population'
                )),
                'color': custom_colors[continent]
            },
            'name': continent
        }
        frame['data'].append(data_dict)

    figure['frames'].append(frame)
    slider_step = {'args': [
        [year],
        {'frame': {'duration': 300, 'redraw': False},
         'mode': 'immediate',
       'transition': {'duration': 300}}
     ],
     'label': year,
     'method': 'animate'}
    sliders_dict['steps'].append(slider_step)

figure['layout']['sliders'] = [sliders_dict]

icreate_animations(figure)
```

and a sample from the dataset:

```
,country,continent,year,Country_code,Total_population,Life_satisfaction,GDP_per_capita
62,Afghanistan,Asia,2008,AFG,29839994.0,3.723589897,1298.14315888
63,Afghanistan,Asia,2009,AFG,30577756.0,4.401778221,1531.17399272
64,Afghanistan,Asia,2010,AFG,31411743.0,4.75838089,1614.25500126
65,Afghanistan,Asia,2011,AFG,32358260.0,3.83171916,1660.73985618
66,Afghanistan,Asia,2012,AFG,33397058.0,3.782937527,1839.27357928
67,Afghanistan,Asia,2013,AFG,34499915.0,3.572100401,1814.15582533
167,Albania,Europe,2007,ALB,3169665.0,4.634251595,8447.88228539
169,Albania,Europe,2009,ALB,3192723.0,5.485469818,9524.60981095
170,Albania,Europe,2010,ALB,3204284.0,5.268936634,9927.13514733
171,Albania,Europe,2011,ALB,3215988.0,5.867421627,10207.7006745
172,Albania,Europe,2012,ALB,3227373.0,5.510124207,10369.7616592
173,Albania,Europe,2013,ALB,3238316.0,4.550647736,10504.0930888
242,Algeria,Africa,2010,DZA,35468208.0,5.46356678,12870.2162376
243,Algeria,Africa,2011,DZA,35980193.0,5.317194462,12989.9549601
244,Algeria,Africa,2012,DZA,36485828.0,5.604595661,13161.566464
451,Angola,Africa,2011,AGO,19618432.0,5.589000702,5911.25433387
452,Angola,Africa,2012,AGO,20162517.0,4.360249996,5998.63860099
```

Comment: a code sample with the issue would be  easy to debug

Comment: I edited the question, thanks (and sorry for the late reply).

Comment: @NarenMurali Seems like there already is a similar (unanswered) question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058892/using-plotly-in-jupyter-to-create-animated-chart-in-off-line-mode). And I tried but I cannot import the command icreate_animations from plotly.offline.

Comment: I found the problem, its the grid option you are using, its only available in plotly online, do you want to generate the graph using plotly online or offline? also icreate_animations does not exist for plotly offline you need to use iplot

Comment: yeah, I am trying to do that offline, I guessed that was the problem but I cannot figure out a way around it. Any ideas?

Comment: working on the fix right now, hold on :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So lets start with the issues in the code.

1. You are using `from plotly.grid_objs import Grid, Column` to make the graph but this is a functionality of plotly online, I have substituted your logic for grid with a simple dataframe, which basically does the same thing.
2. Second, I noticed that the graph was not displaying data, after analyzing I finally found out that you had set the range for X-Axis to `[30, 85]`, but the X-Axis values between `1-15k`.

Please find below my updated code. I hope this solves your issue.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from __future__ import division
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly.graph_objs import *
init_notebook_mode()

from plotly.grid_objs import Grid, Column
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF 

dataset=pd.read_csv('god_mod_copia.csv')

years_from_col = set(dataset['year'])
years_ints = sorted(list(years_from_col))
years = [str(year) for year in years_ints]
# make list of continents
continents = []
for continent in dataset['continent']:
    if continent not in continents: 
        continents.append(continent)
df = pd.DataFrame()
# make grid
for year in years:
    for continent in continents:
        dataset_by_year = dataset[dataset['year'] == int(year)]
        dataset_by_year_and_cont = dataset_by_year[dataset_by_year['continent'] == continent]
        for col_name in dataset_by_year_and_cont:
            # each column name is unique
            temp = '{year}+{continent}+{header}_grid'.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header=col_name
            )
            #if dataset_by_year_and_cont[col_name].size != 0:
            df = df.append({'value': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont[col_name]), 'key': temp}, ignore_index=True)

figure = {
    'data': [],
    'layout': {},
    'frames': []
}
figure['layout']['xaxis'] = {'title': 'GDP per Capita', 'type': 'log', 'autorange': True} #was not set properly
figure['layout']['yaxis'] = {'title': 'Life Expectancy', 'autorange': True} #was not set properly
figure['layout']['hovermode'] = 'closest'
figure['layout']['showlegend'] = True
figure['layout']['sliders'] = {
    'args': [
        'slider.value', {
            'duration': 400,
            'ease': 'cubic-in-out'
        }
    ],
    'initialValue': '2007',
    'plotlycommand': 'animate',
    'values': years,
    'visible': True
}
figure['layout']['updatemenus'] = [
    {
        'buttons': [
            {
                'args': [None, {'frame': {'duration': 500, 'redraw': False},
                         'fromcurrent': True, 'transition': {'duration': 300, 'easing': 'quadratic-in-out'}}],
                'label': 'Play',
                'method': 'animate'
            },
            {
                'args': [[None], {'frame': {'duration': 0, 'redraw': False}, 'mode': 'immediate',
                'transition': {'duration': 0}}],
                'label': 'Pause',
                'method': 'animate'
            }
        ],
        'direction': 'left',
        'pad': {'r': 10, 't': 87},
        'showactive': False,
        'type': 'buttons',
        'x': 0.1,
        'xanchor': 'right',
        'y': 0,
        'yanchor': 'top'
    }
]

sliders_dict = {
    'active': 0,
    'yanchor': 'top',
    'xanchor': 'left',
    'currentvalue': {
        'font': {'size': 20},
        'prefix': 'Year:',
        'visible': True,
        'xanchor': 'right'
    },
    'transition': {'duration': 300, 'easing': 'cubic-in-out'},
    'pad': {'b': 10, 't': 50},
    'len': 0.9,
    'x': 0.1,
    'y': 0,
    'steps': []
}



custom_colors = {
    'Asia': 'rgb(171, 99, 250)',
    'Europe': 'rgb(230, 99, 250)',
    'Africa': 'rgb(99, 110, 250)',
    'Americas': 'rgb(25, 211, 243)',
    #'Oceania': 'rgb(9, 255, 255)' 
    'Oceania': 'rgb(50, 170, 255)'
}

col_name_template = '{year}+{continent}+{header}_grid'
year = 2007
for continent in continents:
    data_dict = {
        'x': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
            year=year, continent=continent, header='GDP_per_capita'
        ), 'value'].values[0],
        'y': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
            year=year, continent=continent, header='Life_satisfaction'
        ), 'value'].values[0],
        'mode': 'markers',
        'text': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
            year=year, continent=continent, header='country'
        ), 'value'].values[0],
        'marker': {
            'sizemode': 'area',
            'sizeref': 200000,
            'size': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header='Total_population'
            ), 'value'].values[0],
            'color': custom_colors[continent]
        },
        'name': continent
    }
    figure['data'].append(data_dict)

for year in years:
    frame = {'data': [], 'name': str(year)}
    for continent in continents:
        data_dict = {
            'x': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header='GDP_per_capita'
            ), 'value'].values[0],
            'y': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header='Life_satisfaction'
            ), 'value'].values[0],
            'mode': 'markers',
            'text': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header='country'
            ), 'value'].values[0],
            'marker': {
                'sizemode': 'area',
                'sizeref': 200000,
                'size': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
                    year=year, continent=continent, header='Total_population'
                ), 'value'].values[0],
                'color': custom_colors[continent]
            },
            'name': continent
        }
        frame['data'].append(data_dict)

    figure['frames'].append(frame) #this block was indented and should not have been.
    slider_step = {'args': [
        [year],
        {'frame': {'duration': 300, 'redraw': False},
         'mode': 'immediate',
       'transition': {'duration': 300}}
     ],
     'label': year,
     'method': 'animate'}
    sliders_dict['steps'].append(slider_step)


figure['layout']['sliders'] = [sliders_dict]
iplot(figure, config={'scrollzoom': True})
```

Comment: It totally works. You helped me more than once in the last few days, I am very grateful :)

Comment: @NarenMurali do you know how to make offline python version of this example - https://plot.ly/r/cumulative-animations/ ? It's the one with Cumulative Lines Animation.

Comment: @Helena Will check how to do it! if I get a way, will reply here, else I couldn't solve it :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's an edited version of Naren Murali's code (his code doesn't work out of the box anymore).

There were corrections needed to make it compatible with the publicly available data set from the tutorial referred by OP. Some plotly libraries/functions had to be updated to work with latest plotly (4.7.1).

```
from __future__ import division
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import chart_studio.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode()

from chart_studio.grid_objs import Grid, Column
from plotly import figure_factory as FF 

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv'
dataset = pd.read_csv(url)

years_from_col = set(dataset['year'])
years_ints = sorted(list(years_from_col))
years = [str(year) for year in years_ints]
# make list of continents
continents = []
for continent in dataset['continent']:
    if continent not in continents: 
        continents.append(continent)
df = pd.DataFrame()
# make grid
for year in years:
    for continent in continents:
        dataset_by_year = dataset[dataset['year'] == int(year)]
        dataset_by_year_and_cont = dataset_by_year[dataset_by_year['continent'] == continent]
        for col_name in dataset_by_year_and_cont:
            # each column name is unique
            temp = '{year}+{continent}+{header}_grid'.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header=col_name
            )
            #if dataset_by_year_and_cont[col_name].size != 0:
            df = df.append({'value': list(dataset_by_year_and_cont[col_name]), 'key': temp}, ignore_index=True)

figure = {
    'data': [],
    'layout': {},
    'frames': []
}
figure['layout']['xaxis'] = {'title': 'GDP per Capita', 'type': 'log', 'autorange': True} #was not set properly
figure['layout']['yaxis'] = {'title': 'Life Expectancy', 'autorange': True} #was not set properly
figure['layout']['hovermode'] = 'closest'
figure['layout']['showlegend'] = True
figure['layout']['sliders'] = {
    'args': [
        'slider.value', {
            'duration': 400,
            'ease': 'cubic-in-out'
        }
    ],
    'initialValue': '2007',
    'plotlycommand': 'animate',
    'values': years,
    'visible': True
}
figure['layout']['updatemenus'] = [
    {
        'buttons': [
            {
                'args': [None, {'frame': {'duration': 500, 'redraw': False},
                         'fromcurrent': True, 'transition': {'duration': 300, 'easing': 'quadratic-in-out'}}],
                'label': 'Play',
                'method': 'animate'
            },
            {
                'args': [[None], {'frame': {'duration': 0, 'redraw': False}, 'mode': 'immediate',
                'transition': {'duration': 0}}],
                'label': 'Pause',
                'method': 'animate'
            }
        ],
        'direction': 'left',
        'pad': {'r': 10, 't': 87},
        'showactive': False,
        'type': 'buttons',
        'x': 0.1,
        'xanchor': 'right',
        'y': 0,
        'yanchor': 'top'
    }
]

sliders_dict = {
    'active': 0,
    'yanchor': 'top',
    'xanchor': 'left',
    'currentvalue': {
        'font': {'size': 20},
        'prefix': 'Year:',
        'visible': True,
        'xanchor': 'right'
    },
    'transition': {'duration': 300, 'easing': 'cubic-in-out'},
    'pad': {'b': 10, 't': 50},
    'len': 0.9,
    'x': 0.1,
    'y': 0,
    'steps': []
}



custom_colors = {
    'Asia': 'rgb(171, 99, 250)',
    'Europe': 'rgb(230, 99, 250)',
    'Africa': 'rgb(99, 110, 250)',
    'Americas': 'rgb(25, 211, 243)',
    #'Oceania': 'rgb(9, 255, 255)' 
    'Oceania': 'rgb(50, 170, 255)'
}

col_name_template = '{year}+{continent}+{header}_grid'
year = 1952
for continent in continents:
    data_dict = {
        'x': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
            year=year, continent=continent, header='gdpPercap'
        ), 'value'].values[0],
        'y': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
            year=year, continent=continent, header='lifeExp'
        ), 'value'].values[0],
        'mode': 'markers',
        'text': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
            year=year, continent=continent, header='country'
        ), 'value'].values[0],
        'marker': {
            'sizemode': 'area',
            'sizeref': 200000,
            'size': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header='pop'
            ), 'value'].values[0],
            'color': custom_colors[continent]
        },
        'name': continent
    }
    figure['data'].append(data_dict)

for year in years:
    frame = {'data': [], 'name': str(year)}
    for continent in continents:
        data_dict = {
            'x': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header='gdpPercap'
            ), 'value'].values[0],
            'y': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header='lifeExp'
            ), 'value'].values[0],
            'mode': 'markers',
            'text': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
                year=year, continent=continent, header='country'
            ), 'value'].values[0],
            'marker': {
                'sizemode': 'area',
                'sizeref': 200000,
                'size': df.loc[df['key']==col_name_template.format(
                    year=year, continent=continent, header='pop'
                ), 'value'].values[0],
                'color': custom_colors[continent]
            },
            'name': continent
        }
        frame['data'].append(data_dict)

    figure['frames'].append(frame) #this block was indented and should not have been.
    slider_step = {'args': [
        [year],
        {'frame': {'duration': 300, 'redraw': False},
         'mode': 'immediate',
       'transition': {'duration': 300}}
     ],
     'label': year,
     'method': 'animate'}
    sliders_dict['steps'].append(slider_step)


figure['layout']['sliders'] = [sliders_dict]
iplot(figure, config={'scrollZoom': True})
```